# Map box TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 't.tiles[0].match(formatPattern)')

Tags: javascript, meteor, mapbox

Using the MOST basic example, I'm trying to load a simple map that I made in Mapbox Studio.

I get an:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating't.tiles[0].match(formatPattern)')
```

Error when simply substituting my map for the sample map.

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'myacct.mapid').setView([41.5, -71.3], 10);
```

Has anyone else seen this issue?

Comment: have you fixed the issue?